# the Ref. hook is not showing the component details. while consoling the ref.current, it showing the undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**(code)**

I have assigned the ref hook over the rightcompX div, when I render this component it will consol out undefined.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {gsap} from 'gsap';
import RingGraph from '../../../components/RingGraph/RingGraph';
import './CR.css';

const InterviewReport = (props) => {

    const Cbox = useRef()

    useState(()=>{
        // gsap.from(CRbox.current,{opacity:0,duration:0.8,x:-40})
        **console.log(Cbox)**
    },[])
    return (
        <>
            <div className="rightCompX" ref={Cbox}>

                <div className="close" onClick={props.close}>
                    close
                </div>

                <div className="title">
                    candidate Report
                </div>
                .....
    )
}

export default InterviewReport;
```

Comment: Seems you've used the wrong hook, `useState` instead of `useEffect`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to use `useEffect()` hook, not `useState()`